# Can't load module that imports css via ember-auto-import

Tags: javascript, webpack, ember.js, ckeditor

I am trying to build an ember 3.25 application that imports the `CkEditor` via `ember-auto-import`

I was able to get the editor working fine by adding the following to my `package.json`:

```
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^27.0.0",
```

and adding the following to my ember component:

```
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

...

didInsertElement() {
  var editor = ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
      ...
    });
}
```

But when I tried to add the `ImageResize` module via:

```
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image": "^27.0.0",
```

and in my component ([as instructed here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image.html#using-resize-handles)):

```
import Image from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/image';
import ImageResize from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/image-resize';
```

I was initially seeing errors that read: `'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: webpack returned errors to ember-auto-import` so I ran `AUTO_IMPORT_VERBOSE=true ember serve`

I now am seeing errors that ckeditor can't `@import` nested `.css`:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/theme/components/toolbar/toolbar.css 6:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (6:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  */
|
> @import "../../mixins/_unselectable.css";
```

Or use ES6 syntax:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/theme/components/dropdown/toolbardropdown.css 6:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|  */
|
> :root {
```

and errors where it tries to include svg files:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-widget/theme/icons/drag-handle.svg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M4 0v1H1v3H0V.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 0H4zm8 0h3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V4h-1V1h-3V0zM4 16H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5V12h1v3h3v1zm8 0v-1h3v-3h1v3.5a.5.5 0
 0 1-.5.5H12z"/><path fill-opacity=".256" d="M1 1h14v14H1z"/><g class="ck-icon__selected-indicator"><path d="M7 0h2v1H7V0zM0 7h1v2H0V7zm15 0h1v2h-1V7zm-8 8h2v1H7v-1z"/><path fill-opacity=".254" d="M1 1h14
v14H1z"/></g></svg>
```

Based on this message:

> ```
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> ```

It seems like I need to add some webpack loaders to ember, but I'm really not sure how to do that. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/image` [imports a CSS file](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/blob/cfeee6a88e01ef960845d79a3ef861f28f9cb95a/packages/ckeditor5-image/src/image.js#L17). As CKEditor uses CSS-in-JS and other features not part of ECMAScript specification you need to configure webpack to support it. CKEditor's documentation includes a [minimal configuration example](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html#webpack-configuration):

```js
const CKEditorWebpackPlugin = require("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin");
const { styles } = require("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    // ...

    new CKEditorWebpackPlugin({
      // See https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/ui-language.html
      language: "pl",
    }),
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
        use: ["raw-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader",
            options: {
              injectType: "singletonStyleTag",
              attributes: {
                "data-cke": true,
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: styles.getPostCssConfig({
              themeImporter: {
                themePath: require.resolve("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark"),
              },
              minify: true,
            }),
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Ember Auto Import allows you to provide custom webpack configuration as `autoImport.webpack` configuration key:

```js
// ember-cli-build.js

let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  autoImport: {
    webpack: {
      // extra webpack configuration goes here
    },
  },
});
```

Please reach out to [Ember Auto Import's documentation](https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import#customizing-build-behavior) for details.

Putting both together something like this *should* work:

```js
// ember-cli-build.js

const CKEditorWebpackPlugin = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin');
const { styles } = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils');

let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  autoImport: {
    webpack: {
      plugins: [
        new CKEditorWebpackPlugin({
          // See https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/ui-language.html
          language: "pl",
        }),
      ],
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
            use: ["raw-loader"],
          },
          {
            test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: "style-loader",
                options: {
                  injectType: "singletonStyleTag",
                  attributes: {
                    "data-cke": true,
                  },
                },
              },
              {
                loader: "postcss-loader",
                options: styles.getPostCssConfig({
                  themeImporter: {
                    themePath: require.resolve(
                      "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark"
                    ),
                  },
                  minify: true,
                }),
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
});
```

## UPDATE

This solution **almost** worked but there are a few things to note:

Importing `ImageResize` from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/image-resize'; along side the `ClassicEditor` from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic' did not work! Apparently that will cause duplicate-module-errors.

So instead, follow the instructions on how to [build from source](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html#scenario-2-building-from-source) after doing that, I found that the ckeditor styling was not loading in ember until I followed the instructions on [extracting CSS](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/advanced-setup.html#option-extracting-css) and then everything worked!

Here are the relevant pieces from my `package.json`:

```
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckfinder": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-cloud-services": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils": "^24.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin": "^24.4.2",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-easy-image": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark": "^27.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing": "^27.0.0",
"css-loader": "^5.2.2",
"mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.5.0",
"postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
"raw-loader": "^3.1.0",
"style-loader": "^2.0.0"
```

And my ember-cli-build.js file:

```
  const CKEditorWebpackPlugin = require("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin");
  const { styles } = require("@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils");
  const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require( 'mini-css-extract-plugin' );


  module.exports = function (defaults) {
    let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {

     cssModules: {
       includeExtensionInModulePath: true,
     },

      sassOptions: {
       inputFiles: [  
         '/app/styles/app.scss',  
        ],
        includePaths: ['app', 'app/components']
      },
      // Add options here
      autoImport: {
        webpack: {
          plugins: [
           new CKEditorWebpackPlugin({
              // See https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/ui-language.html
              // language: "en",
            }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin( {
              filename: 'ckeditor.css'
            } )
          ],
          module: {
            rules: [
              {
                test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
                use: ["raw-loader"],
              },
              {
                test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css$/,
                use: [
                  MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                  'css-loader',
                  {
                    loader: "postcss-loader",
                    options: styles.getPostCssConfig({
                    themeImporter: {
                      themePath: require.resolve(
                        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark"
                      ),
                    },
                    minify: true,
                  }),
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  });


  return app.toTree();
};
```

And my ck-editor.js file (that I keep in the same directory as my component):

```
import ClassicEditorBase from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';
import EssentialsPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import UploadAdapterPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder/src/uploadadapter';
import AutoformatPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat/src/autoformat';
import BoldPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
import ItalicPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic';
import BlockQuotePlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote/src/blockquote';
// import EasyImagePlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-easy-image/src/easyimage';
import HeadingPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/heading';
import ImagePlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/image';
import ImageCaptionPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagecaption';
import ImageStylePlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagestyle';
import ImageToolbarPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagetoolbar';
import ImageUploadPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageupload';
import LinkPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link';
import ListPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/list';
import ParagraphPlugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';
import ImageResize from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageresize';

export default class ClassicEditor extends ClassicEditorBase {}

ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins = [
    EssentialsPlugin,
    UploadAdapterPlugin,
    AutoformatPlugin,
    BoldPlugin,
    ItalicPlugin,
    BlockQuotePlugin,
    // EasyImagePlugin,
    HeadingPlugin,
    ImagePlugin,
    ImageCaptionPlugin,
    ImageStylePlugin,
    ImageToolbarPlugin,
    ImageUploadPlugin,
        ImageResize,
    LinkPlugin,
    ListPlugin,
    ParagraphPlugin
];

ClassicEditor.defaultConfig = {
    toolbar: {
        items: [
            'heading',
            '|',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'link',
            'bulletedList',
            'numberedList',
            'uploadImage',
            'blockQuote',
            'undo',
            'redo'
        ]
    },
    image: {
        toolbar: [
            'imageStyle:full',
            'imageStyle:side',
            '|',
            'imageTextAlternative'
        ]
    },
    language: 'en'
};
```

Now, from my component, I can just call:

```
import ClassicEditor from './ck-editor';

...

didInsertElement() {
  var editor = ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
      ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped get me on the right path. I'm going to make a few changes to your answer now that I have it working!